# Proxy PanResponder / gestures to another component

Tags: react-native

I have a component that response to gestures and another component smaller in size that's overlaying it (position: 'absolute').

Is there a way for the overlaying component to proxy gestures to the component under it or to a specific component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: what you need is the 'pointerEvents' View property.

In my case, I had to set it to 'box-none' which means the View ignores gestures and forwards it on, but elements inside the view (like buttons) do get the events if clicked on.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#pointerevents